# How to calculate these limit superiors and limit inferiors?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Let $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$ be two sequences of positive real numbers, such that 
$$a_{2k} = \frac{1}{3^k}, \, \, \,  a_{2k-1} = \frac{1}{2^k},$$ 
and 
$$b_{2k} = \frac{1}{4^{k-1}} , \, \, \,  b_{2k-1} = \frac{1}{2^{2k-1}}$$ for $k= 1, 2, 3, \ldots$.

Then how to compute $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}, \, \, \, \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup  \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}, \, \, \, \lim_{n\to\infty} \inf \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}, \, \, \,  \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}? $$

And, how to compute 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf \sqrt[n]{a_n}, \, \, \, \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{a_n}, \, \, \, \lim_{n\to\infty} \inf \sqrt[n]{b_n}, \, \, \, \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{b_n}? $$

My effort:

For $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, we obtain 
$$\frac{a_{2k}}{a_{2k-1}} = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k, $$ 
and 
$$\frac{a_{2k+1}}{a_{2k}} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k; $$ 
so 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^k = 0,$$ 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} = \lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{1}{2} \cdot\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)^k = +\infty. $$ 
And for $k = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$, we obtain
$$\frac{b_{2k}}{b_{2k-1}} = \frac{1/2^{2k-2}}{1/2^{2k-1}} =  2, $$ and 
$$\frac{b_{2k+1}}{b_{2k}} = \frac{1/2^{2k+1}}{1/2^{2k-2}} = \frac{1}{8}; $$ 
so 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = 2,$$ and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \inf \frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n} = \frac{1}{8}.$$

Am I right? And, how to go ahead with the computation of these limits for the $n$th roots?

Comment: Don't post many questions in a post.

Comment: Sorry for any inconvenience, but actually I'm reading Walter Rudin's PRINCIPLES OF MATHEMATICAL ANALYSIS, 3rd edition, and it is in the examples in section 3.35 (a) and (b) that I've encountered these limits, which I found a bit hard to figure out for myself and so thought it prudent to consult the worthy Math SE community.